# auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a project file containing project/.env, project/frontend, and project/server, and in project/frontend, I also have a .env (project/frontend/.env), which contains:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="xxxxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="xxxxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="xxxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="xxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="xxxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID="xxxxxxx";
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID="xxxxxxx";
```

I also have project/frontend/config/firebase.js like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, auth, storage };
```

I tried to copy paste the same value in .env to firebase.js and it worked. I tried to print the values in project/frontend/src/components/auth/Login.js where I get the error when logging in, and the printed value is correct. How can I fix this?

eidted:
The Login.js is like this:

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

export default function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const { currentUser, login, setError } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(currentUser) {
            navigate("/");
        }
    }, [currentUser, navigate]);

    async function handleFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            setError("");
            setLoading(true);
            await login(email, password)
            navigate("/");
        } catch(e) {
            setError(e.message);
        }

        setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="authbox">
                <h2>Brag Game</h2>

                <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/login" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="login-email">email: </label>
                            <input
                                type="email"
                                id="login-email"
                                autoComplete="email"
                                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="login-password">password: </label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                id="login-password"
                                autoComplete="current-password"
                                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="loginbutton" disabled={loading}>Sign In</button>
                </form>
                <div className="authtips">Don't have an account?<br />
                    <div className="authlink"><Link to="/register">Register here!</Link></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You mean to say, console.log() gives you correct values in Login.js but it giving you error, right ?

Comment: I couldn't find `REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY` in your .env file. Are you sure you have an entry in .env?

Comment: @MaulikPatel yes

Comment: Please share the Login.js code here, So - we can review it.

Comment: @MaulikPatel Just edited to add Login.js

Comment: What error you're seeing on screen while click on login?

Comment: @MaulikPatel It's the error on the title: Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.).

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same error, where I prefaced all env variables with `REACT_APP_...`, and tried accessing them using `process.env` like you are in firebase.js. However, I was noticing like you are that when logging them to the console, they were getting loaded correctly, so that means you're fine for now. I realized after a bit that there was no actual error on my end, but some kind of network error that was causing the issue of not being able to connect to the database. Did you try restarting your server after you ran into this issue? Sometimes, that itself may help.

Comment: I did try restarting the server, but still the same error